# Jump to named anchor on new page - images causing offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, hyperlink

On our WordPress website, we have some links in our sidebar that load a new page on the same site. All the sidebar links are to different pages.

I have added a hash name to the link target so that when the new page loads we can take the user to a specific part of the target page.

The trouble is, the page contains some images that cause the target position to shift when the images have loaded. I am using the following line inside jQuery's document.ready function to wait until the page(or the problem image) has loaded then smooth scroll to the anchor but it's not working…

```
jQuery(document.body).scrollTop(jQuery('#stockistDetails').offset().top);
```

The link text I'm using looks like…

```
http://findyourdreamdress.co.uk/dresses/lillian-west/6343-lillian-west/?stockist_id=1393#stockistDetails
http://findyourdreamdress.co.uk/dresses/lillian-west/6343-lillian-west/?stockist_id=1132#stockistDetails
```

And on the target page I have an anchor that looks like…

```
<a name="stockistDetails" id="stockistDetails"></a>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here:-(

Comment: Instead of using `$(document).ready()` try: `$(window).load( "article.html #target" );`

Comment: Set attributes width and height for all images if fixed size required or set logic in `window.onload` event

Comment: It's a responsive layout - I'm not sure I can set fixed attributes?

Answer (score 0):

From a UX perspective on a slow connection the screen is going to 'jump' when the image finishes loading. I know you said you're using smooth scrolling to glide to the target, but for some users this will still feel like a 'jump'. Plus, if the image is taking some time to load the user may already begin to read something on the page whilst waiting and may get annoyed when you finally have the smooth scroll click in.

So, one approach is to set the attributes, even in a responsive design you should be able to do this using relative dimensions rather than absolutes, perhaps with some JS help if necessary.

Another approach is to load a smaller image initially and then load the higher resolution version when the user clicks or hovers over it. You can see this in action in a number of retailer's sites nowadays.